# File is writable but occasionally the error: `failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Tags: php

I have a 404.log file in my /public_html/logs folder.

When a 404 page is displayed, PHP appends the information to 404.log file, which gives me information about my website and who's trying to access what.

For some reason, sometimes I get the error `Permission Denied`.  The file is writeable, executable and it gets written to on a daily basis - It works fine if I go to a page that doesnt exist, the file gets written to and I can see the entry in there.

However I get errors flagged up because permission is denied, and I think it is happening because robots or someone is trying to brute force their way into my website - for instance - the URIs I get are;

`/static/../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd.
/cms/www/loader.php/system/"><iMg
/webtrees/modules_v3/googlemap/wt_v3_street_view.php?map=">
/sites/all/modules/fckeditor/fckeditor/editor/filemanager/connectors/cfm/connector.cfm?Command=GetFolders&Type=File&CurrentFolder=%2F`

So my guess is that the file is already open by the same script but because the website is being accessed so fast it results in permission denied.  Is there way to prevent this, or write asynchronously somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should just look at the access logs that your webserver provides for you to see how many 404's occur. If you must do it through PHP there's a couple of things you can do.

There might be an option for parallel writing, but I would imagine that to give you a very weird file with a lot of errors mixed through one another.

You might change the way you log to writing to a database rather than a file. Clearly databases are much better suited for many requests at the same time, and will just create a new record for each error that occures.

Alternatively, you could implement your own logging layer that is basically just an im memory queue, that constantly tries to write to file whenever it is not empty. This way you can buffer your logs. You will have to think about saving the timestamps for when something happens though, as well as keeping track of how much memory your queue is using.

Im pretty sure there exist many libraries that take care of this for you as well. The people that wrote those libraries ran into these problems as well, and created generid solutions for them, so that you don't have to worry about it now.

Comment: You're right, I'm going to use the access_log file instead from now on.